# Django restframework serialization of a ManytoMany relation

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm on a project using Django and the restdjangoframework

I'm in my Serializer.py where I wrote all my serialization classes, I did the serialization of a foreignKey and a OnetoOnefield but I didn't understand how to do the serialization of a ManytoMany relation

here is an exemple of my code:

```
class CV(models.Model):
    numtel = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    datecv= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True,blank=False,null=False)
    pathcv = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    compteCand = models.OneToOneField('CompteCandidat',related_name="infocand")
    diplome = models.ManyToManyField('Diplome', related_name="infoDiplome", blank=True)
    #######################################################
    def __str__(self):
        return self.numtel
    def __CVs__(self):
        return self.compteCand.all()



class Diplome(Competence):
    type=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    domaine=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    specialite=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    annee=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False,blank=False,null=False)
    #######################################################
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
        return self.domaine
        return self.specialite
        return self.annee
```

I also need to know if i have to add in Diplome a relation ManytoMany toward CV or not

and do I wrote my serialisation class like this :

```
class CVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    infocand= CompteCandidatSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)
    infoDiplomee=CompetenceSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model =CV
        fields=('first_name','last_name','email','numtel','infocand','infoDiplome')

class DiplomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =Diplome
        fields=
(....??)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize a ManyToMany field, just write a serializer as you would for a OneToOne, but add the `many=True` kwarg.
If you want to serialize them in a special way, for instance here, field 'diplome' being serialized as a count of all diplomes, you would use a `SerializerMethodField`.

Oh, and your field `infoDiplomee` != `infoDiplome` in your CVSerializer.